# $.post() not working as expected jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post, html-lists

This is my code for adding a `<li>` before a `<li>` in `<ul>`.

```
$.post("page.php", data,function(data,success)
{
        var s=data.split("|");
        var sl=s.length-1;
        for(var i=0;i<sl;i++)
        {
            var sep='<li class="atItem" id="atItem'+i+'">'+s[i]+'</li>';
            $('ul.pageCont').children('li#atItemLast').before(sep);
        }
});
```

**Page.php returns:** `name|` on `echo $name`

But my problem is that two `<li>` is added to `<ul>`. What is the mistake i am doing?

I had checked value for `sl` it alerts `1`.

Comment: Why are you testing `if(success=="success")`? If that method is called, you know it's a success.

Comment: What's the point of doing `li#atItemLast` instead of `#atItemLast`? ID selectors are faster than general selectors.

Comment: You are splitting a string, which will return an array with two indices?

Comment: @JanDvorak success is a variable thats contains error and success which is returned after ajax call

Comment: @adeneo good guess. Latest edit confirms that true. Time to write an answer.

Comment: @Harikrishnan if AJAX error occurs, this callback doesn't get called. This is a `success` callback, not an `always` callback.

Comment: What he said ^^^^ - There's no reason at all to check if the call was successful in a success callback only fired if it was successful!

Comment: @adeneo yes. But i am decrementing `1` from length.

Comment: @adeneo i had removed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does'nt seem to be a reason for iterating over an array just to get the first value, just use `[0]` ?

```
$.post("page.php", data, function(data) {
    var s   = data.split("|")[0], // first instance
        sep = $('<li />', {'class':'atItem0', id:'s0'});

    $('#atItemLast').before(sep);
});
```

Comment: it again has 2 <li> created

Comment: @Harikrishnan - That's simply not possible, unless the entire $.post function is called twice. Place a console.log right above the $.post function and see if it's triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

Cause "name|" splits into "name" and "" (empty string)

See Below.

```
var str = "name|";
var arr = str.split("|");

console.log(arr.length); // 2
console.log(arr[0]); // "name"
console.log(arr[1]); // ""
```